# Change the size of all markers of a KML file with API Google

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

I am trying to make a map that shows several information of a project. I have like 1000 points in Arcgis, each point have a html code that shows specific info of the points (names, location, 1 picture etc..). I export these points to a kml file, so I have the 1000 in a one kml file with all the info. 
What I want to do is format all the markers of the kml file with api Google maps, (size, color etc...), so when I load the map in the web page I can play with size or color of the markers of the kml file. I haven’t found the procedure yet. I don’t know if I the issue well explained.

I mean which is the code to change the size and color of all markers of a kml file with API Google maps.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with the native Google Maps API v3 [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayer) class.  You could import your KML into FusionTables, overlay a [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesLayer) and [style that dynamically](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#fusion_table_styles) or use a third party KML parser like [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/) which parse the KML and render it using native Google Maps API v3 objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try with fusion tables and post the result. I'll search for how to import kml to fusion tables.

Comment: I tried with fusion table but the problem is that only let you use up to 5 tables, so what I did is modify the kml file before uploading it, i found that google always shows the icon in 32x32 px so i create a png image of 32x32px size with 16x16px transparent margins, and now looks samller.